# Array output value is null on separating string value using implode function by comma output displays in exta comma? how to solve it?

Tags: arrays, drupal-7

```
$drstring1 = stristr($drstring, 'DR', false);
//drupal_set_message($drstring1);
$drbrkstring = $drstring1;
$drval = explode('DR', $drbrkstring);
array_shift($drval);
$drdata_array = array();
foreach ($drval as $drv) {
$drdata = process_drstring('DR' . $drv);
$Colarray = array();
foreach ($drdata as $key => $value) {
  array_push($Colarray, $key);
  print 'key='. $key .' <br />';
}
$ColNames = implode(',' ,$Colarray);
 print 'colunames=' .$ColNames.' <br />';



 function process_drstring($string) {
  $result = array();
  $tag_text = array(
  'DR' => 'segmenttag',
  '01' => 'dateofentry',
  '02' => 'dispute_remarks1',
  '03' => 'dispute_remarks2',
  '04' => 'dispute_remarks3',
  '05' => 'dispute_remarks4',
  '06' => 'dispute_remarks5',
  '07' => 'dispute_remarks6',
  );
$tag = substr($string, 0, 2);
$length = substr($string, 2, 2);
$data = substr($string, 4, $length);
$result[$tag_text[$tag]] = $data;
$newstring = substr($string, $length + 4, strlen($string));
if ($newstring) {
$newresult = process_drstring($newstring);
$result = array_merge($result, $newresult);
return $result;
}
else {
return $result;
}
}
 output:
  key=segmenttag 
  key= 
  key=dateofentry 
  key=dispute_remarks2 
  key=dispute_remarks1 
  key=dispute_remarks3 
  key=dispute_remarks4 
  key=dispute_remarks5 
  key=dispute_remarks6
```

colunames=segmenttag,,dateofentry,dispute_remarks2,dispute_remarks1,dispute_remarks3,dispute_remarks4,dispute_remarks5,dispute_remarks6

From this function , I need to get an columnames, but i'm receiving an extra key='' key element.

getting extra key value. Key='' it should not appear. Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: I assume `colunames` is your imploded array? What is your input value, meaning, what is "inside" `$drdata`?

Comment: yes colnames is imploded array. My input value is colnames and $drdata is null value.  so i don't want to display the key=' ' element.   Its throws an error in database.

Comment: It can't be null, where does it get all the data from? There must be somewhere that $drdata is obtained from. Please supply additional code in order for me to help you further.

Comment: What does $drstring contain? This is the key element that defines why the above code does not produce the output you expect.

Comment: $drstring does not contain any value right now??

Comment: Not at the end, at the beginning, what value does `$drstring` contain?